# Can I non-manually add a comma to the end of hundreds of lines of text?

Tags: gedit, sed

I have hundreds of rows of text like so:

aaabbbccc
dddeeefff
ggghhhiii

They do not have a space at the end.

I want to add a comma to the end of each line. Is there a way to non-manually achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `sed`

```
$ sed 's/$/,/' file
aaabbbccc,
dddeeefff,
ggghhhiii,
```

It *should* be possible to do the same with `gedit`'s search and replace by checking `Regular expression` box; if that doesn't work then replace `\n` by `,\n` and modify the last line if necessary.

---

Some other command-line ways:

```
awk -vORS=',\n' 1 file
```

or similarly

```
perl -lpe '$\=",\n"' file
```

Answer (score 1):

If your rows of text are in the file `ttt` and you want commas in blank lines,

```
sed 's/$/,/'  ttt
```

else if you want blank lines to remain blank

```
sed 's/.$/&,/'  ttt
```

Redirect the output to a file `output` like so

```
sed 's/.$/&,/'  ttt > output
```